# How to install Java6 add-on for IE9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser-addons, internet-explorer-9, sun-java6-jdk

I have an internal web app I need to test using java 1.6 on Internet Explorer.

I installed the java6 jdk but there seems to be no add-on included for IE. I tried the 6 JRE too but nothing shows up in IE manage add-ons (and when I run the test on java.com it fails and a dialog from IE telling me the page is attempting to run java is brought up).

Any tips on getting java6 to run in the browser?

Comment: It should be as simple as just installing it.  You do understand that the Java 6 browser add-on is not secure right?

Comment: I understand, maybe this is why and IE won't allow java6 to install itself as a plugin?

Comment: IE9 will accept any add-on there is no blacklist or whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Windows7 64bit runs IE 32bit by default. So my 64bit JDK obviously didn't run on that. Just downloaded 64bit IE.

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml